# Find points that are equidistant from 4 points

Tags: python, numpy

This code needs a very long time to find a point. Is there any better way to find a point that is equidistant from 4 given points? A tolerance of 0.5 is fine.

```
import numpy as np

# Define the four 3D points as (x, y, z) coordinates
point1 = np.array([1, 2, 3])
point2 = np.array([3, 4, 5])
point3 = np.array([5, 6, 7])
point4 = np.array([7, 8, 9])

# Set a tolerance for distance equality
tolerance = 0.5

# Calculate the initial average point
average_point = np.mean([point1, point2, point3, point4], axis=0)

while True:
    distances = np.linalg.norm(average_point - np.array([point1, point2, point3, point4]), axis=1)
    max_distance = np.max(distances)
    min_distance = np.min(distances)

    if max_distance - min_distance <= tolerance:
        break

    # Update the average point by moving it closer to the farthest point
    farthest_point = np.argmax(distances)
    average_point = average_point + 0.5 * (point1 - average_point)

print("Average point with relatively equal distances:", average_point)
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the points form a line, so there is simply no equidistant point. The further you go away from them, the better the approximation becomes, but you can continue that until infinity.

Comment: I think, for 4 points to be equidistant from a given point should lie on the circumference of a circle.

Comment: @Goku: Right. In this case though, a 3D-circle called sphere. ;)

Comment: Thank you, the function should show there is no point in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has no solution in general, but an approximation can be obtained using a minimization approach.

If the points are:

```
>>> points = np.array([[10,  2,  3],
...                    [ 3, 40,  5],
...                    [50,  6,  7],
...                    [ 7,  8, 90]])
```

An error function can be defined as the variance of the distances:

```
>>> def distance_error(x, pts):
...     dist = np.sqrt(np.sum((pts - x) ** 2, axis=1))
...     return np.var(dist)
```

Then the best point `p` can be found by minimizing the error function:

```
>>> from scipy.optimize import minimize
>>> p = minimize(distance_error, x0=(0,0,0), args=points).x
>>> p
array([24.10963833, 22.04056223, 45.86305227])
```

And the distances are:

```
>>> np.sqrt(np.sum((points - p)**2, axis=1))
array([49.3755737 , 49.37557368, 49.37557388, 49.37557358])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also solve this algebraically, rather than by geometry or by optimizing/minimizing.

The points have a unique equidistant point if they are distinct and lie on a sphere. This is OK for distinct points except where at least three lie on a line (the case in the original post) or all four are co-planar.

Let the centre be (a,b,c) and the radius be R. Then each of the four points (x,y,z) satisfies

[image]

This multiplies out and rearranges to

[image]

Now, to eliminate R (and the quadratic terms in the centre coordinates a, b, c) subtract the equation for point 1 from point 0, point 2 from point 0, point 3 from point 0. You get three equations which can be written as the matrix equation

[image]

Solve this (by, e.g. Gaussian elimination) for the centre (a,b,c) and then substitute in any of the original equations to get R.

The solution fails if the matrix is not invertible; i.e. if it has zero determinant. This occurs if either two rows are a multiple of each other (three points in a straight line) or one row is a linear combination of the other two (points are coplanar).

```
import numpy as np
import math

def GaussElimination( A, b ):
    SMALL = 1.0e-10
    n = len( A[0] )
    x = np.zeros( n )

    for i in range( n - 1 ):
        # Pivot: swap rows to get largest value in column i
        r = i
        maxA = abs( A[i,i] )
        for k in range( i + 1, n ):
            val = abs( A[k,i] )
            if val > maxA: r, maxA = k, val
        if r != i:
            A[i,i:], A[r,i:] = A[r,i:].copy(), A[i,i:].copy()
            b[i], b[r] = b[r], b[i]
   
        # Row operations to make upper-triangular
        pivot = A[i,i]
        if ( abs( pivot ) < SMALL ): return A, False       # Singular matrix
        for r in range( i + 1, n ):                        # On lower rows
            multiple = A[r,i] / pivot                      # Multiple of row i to clear element in ith column
            A[r,i:] -= multiple * A[i,i:]
            b[r]    -= multiple * b[i]
        if abs( A[n-1,n-1] ) < SMALL: return A, False      # Singular matrix

    # Back-substitute
    for i in range( n-1, -1, -1 ): x[i] = ( b[i] - np.sum( A[i,i+1:] * x[i+1:] ) ) / A[i,i]

    return x, True


####################################################################################################


pts = [ np.array( [ 10.0,  2.0,  3.0 ] ),                       # list of points
        np.array( [  3.0, 40.0,  5.0 ] ),
        np.array( [ 50.0,  6.0,  7.0 ] ),
        np.array( [  7.0,  8.0, 90.0 ] ) ]

A = np.zeros( ( 3, 3 ) )                                        # set up matrix equation for centre
b = np.zeros( 3 )
for i in range( 1, 4 ):
    for j in range( 3 ): A[i-1,j] = pts[0][j] - pts[i][j]
    b[i-1] = 0.5 * np.sum( pts[0] ** 2 - pts[i] ** 2 )

centre, ok = GaussElimination( A, b )                           # solve for centre
if ok:
    R = math.sqrt( np.sum( ( pts[0] - centre ) ** 2 ) )         # find radius (i.e. common distance)
    print( "Centre = ", centre, "\nDistance = ", R )
else:
    print( "Can't find point" )
```

For the case provided by @aerobiomat:

```
Centre =  [24.10963855 22.04056225 45.86305221] 
Distance =  49.375573718630044
```

**EDIT** For those who prefer library routines

If you prefer to use the numpy matrix solver then it's much shorter:

```
import numpy as np
import math

pts = [ np.array( [ 10.0,  2.0,  3.0 ] ),                       # list of points
        np.array( [  3.0, 40.0,  5.0 ] ),
        np.array( [ 50.0,  6.0,  7.0 ] ),
        np.array( [  7.0,  8.0, 90.0 ] ) ]

A = np.zeros( ( 3, 3 ) )                                        # set up matrix equation for centre
b = np.zeros( 3 )
for i in range( 1, 4 ):
    for j in range( 3 ): A[i-1,j] = pts[0][j] - pts[i][j]
    b[i-1] = 0.5 * np.sum( pts[0] ** 2 - pts[i] ** 2 )

try:
    centre = np.linalg.solve( A, b )                            # solve for centre
    R = math.sqrt( np.sum( ( pts[0] - centre ) ** 2 ) )         # find radius (i.e. common distance)
    print( "Centre = ", centre, "\nDistance = ", R )
except np.linalg.LinAlgError:
    print( "Can't find point" )
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a loop for that? Let me show you how to do this in 2D:

[image]

You need to find the point on the same distance from points `A`, `B` and `C`. In order to do that, you need the perpendicular bisector of `A` and `B`, you also take the perpendicular bisector of `A` and `C`, and the intersection of both gives you the point `D`, which is the solution.
In order to prove the latter, the circle is drawn with `D` as the center. As you can see, that circle contains the points `A`, `B` and `C`, proving that indeed `D` lays on the same distance from the three starting points.

Just expand this reasoning to 3D and you have your solution, and as you see, no loops are needed for this.

Comment: I tried but it seems not good. Can you pls take a look?

Answer (score 0):

This one based on the intersection of two bisectors does not work well. @Dominique can you please take a look?

```
import numpy as np

# Define the four 3D points as (x, y, z) coordinates
point1 = np.array([10, 2, 3])
point2 = np.array([3, 40, 5])
point3 = np.array([50, 6, 7])
point4 = np.array([7, 8, 90])

# Calculate the midpoint of a line segment between two points
def midpoint(point1, point2):
    return (point1 + point2) / 2

# Calculate the direction vector of the line
def direction_vector(point1, point2):
    return point2 - point1

# Calculate the negative reciprocal of the slopes in 3D
def perpendicular_slopes_3d(point1, point2):
    return -direction_vector(point1, point2)

# Calculate the equation of the perpendicular bisector in 3D
def perpendicular_bisector_3d(point1, point2):
    mid = midpoint(point1, point2)
    perp_slope = perpendicular_slopes_3d(point1, point2)
    return (mid, perp_slope)

# Calculate the perpendicular bisectors for each pair of points
bisector12 = perpendicular_bisector_3d(point1, point2)
bisector34 = perpendicular_bisector_3d(point3, point4)

# Solve for the intersection point in 3D
mid1, dir1 = bisector12
mid2, dir2 = bisector34

# Calculate the intersection point by finding the point of closest approach between the two lines
dir1_normalized = dir1 / np.linalg.norm(dir1)
dir2_normalized = dir2 / np.linalg.norm(dir2)

# Parameters for the lines
t1 = np.dot(mid2 - mid1, dir1_normalized) / np.dot(dir1_normalized, dir1_normalized)
t2 = np.dot(mid2 - mid1, dir2_normalized) / np.dot(dir2_normalized, dir2_normalized)

intersection_point = mid1 + t1 * dir1_normalized

# Calculate distances between the intersection point and all given points in 3D
distances = [np.linalg.norm(intersection_point - point) for point in [point1, point2, point3, point4]]

# Print the distances
for i, point in enumerate([point1, point2, point3, point4]):
    print(f"Distance between intersection and point {i + 1}: {distances[i]}")

# Print the intersection point
print("Intersection point in 3D:", intersection_point)
```

Its results are

```
Distance between intersection and point 1: 3.9156307702153543
Distance between intersection and point 2: 34.77545347409085
Distance between intersection and point 3: 40.885458802402674
Distance between intersection and point 4: 86.8545619404054
Intersection point in 3D: [9.29158317 5.84569138 3.20240481]
```